# How to filter post content during publish/save routine with str_ireplace()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a function that does a text replacement on the post content when its saved (the_content).

The stub function is below, but how do I obtain a reference to the post content, then return the filtered content back to the "publish_post" routine?

However, my replacement is either not working and/or not passing the updated post_content to the publish function. The values never get replaced.

```
function my_function() {
    global $post;
    $the_content = $post->post_content;
    $text = " test ";
    $post->post_content = str_ireplace($text, '<b>'.$text.'</b>', $the_content  );
    return $post->post_content;
    }
add_action('publish_post', 'my_function');
```

Answer (score 7):

When you mention `the_content`, are you referencing the template tag or the filter hook?

`the_content` as a filter hook only works on post content during database reads, not writes.  The filter to use when modifying post content right before it is save to the db is `content_save_pre`.

**Code Example**

In your plugin or theme's functions.php, add your function, using `$content` as the argument.  Modify the content any way you wish, and be sure to return `$content`.

Then use `add_filter('filter_name', 'function_name')` to run the function when the filter hook is encountered in WordPress.

```
function add_myself($content){
return $content." myself";
}
add_filter('content_save_pre','add_myself');
```

If I write a post that includes:

> "To the end of posts, I like to add"

when saved to the database and displayed on the site, it will read:

> "To the end of posts, I like to add myself".

Your example filter might be revised to look like this:

```
function my_function($content) {
    $text = " test ";
    return str_ireplace($text, '<b>'.$text.'</b>', $content  );
}
add_filter('content_save_pre','my_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to do something like this:

```
function my_function($post) {
  $content = str_ireplace(" test ", '<b>'.$text.'</b>', $post->content);

  return $content;
}
```

Less focus was on the interior of the function, but the idea is that you pass the object to the function in the `()` then call the directly rather than globalizing the value.  It should be more direct that way.

Comment: Thanks Lodge. Looks great, but when I test it, the content remains the same after clicking "Update" on the post editor. I'd like to replace all instances of the word "test" with a bolded replacement...

Answer (score 0):

the passed variable here is $id. This should work:

```
function my_function($id) {
  $the_post = get_post($id);
  $content = str_ireplace(" test ", '<b>'.$text.'</b>', $the_post->post_content);

  return $content;
}
add_action('publish_post', 'my_function');
```

Comment: does not change the post content. Where are you passing $id from? btw, like the name. I'm in bham, al

Comment: @Scott, interesting. In my code I wanted to cover all the bases, so I used three hooks: edit_post, save_post, and publish_post. Doing a search of the WordPress (v. 3.0.1) source I don't immediately see a call for do_action('publish_post'). Maybe try save_post instead?The do_action method WordPress uses do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post), which is where the post ID and post objects are passed.